# Redis proxy ConnectionError

Tags: kubernetes, redis

I have a major problem with the Redis proxy, which often tells me that R2, R1, R0 are DOWN. I also notice that R2 changes its state, but the others don't. When I check the status of the Redis pods, all 3 replicas are fully operational with no restarts and no error messages inside.

- This is the error message I see in the redis proxy: [redis_proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCCiB.png)
- This is in the Redis pod: [redis_pods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKPQq.png)
- Does anyone have an idea about the problem? I'm on redis proxy 2.0.4 and redis redis:5.0.6-alpine

We thought it was related to the new update, but we stopped this deployment and it still continues to happen anyway